# Why I can't build in new iPad Xamarin app?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I try to install my app in new iPad but I have the following error:

> ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.619u2P/extracted/enVisite360.iOS.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)

I'm on Windows using visual studio 2019 16.3.10

I have downloaded all the certificates.

I don't know what to do please help me.

Comment: Check out this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution?tabs=macos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provision your iPad.

> To test on a physical device, the device must be provisioned, and Apple must be informed that the device will be used for testing.

To do this you need to add it to the provisioning profiling:

- got to https://developer.apple.com/
- Add the device UUID to the device list
- update the provisioning profile to include that device
- Re-download the provisioning profiles

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/